# Why can't we use parentheses around a for loop while iterating over a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
a =["mary","had", "a", "little", "lamb"]   
print(len(a))   
for (i in a):  **# this part says invalid syntax**   
    print(i)   


a =["mary","had", "a", "little", "lamb"]   
print(len(a))   
for i in a:   #this works just fine   
    print(i)
```

Comment: @SuryaTej: even if it looks like a function call, it needn't be one. C# has that syntax and still can distinguish between a for loop and a function call. That's the task of a lexer

Comment: but shouldn't the brackets be ignored by the interpreter? like (a+b)/2 and ((a)+(b))/2 mean the same thing?

Comment: @Tanuj no, brackets aren't ever really *ignored* by the interpreter, and they can mean different things in different contexts. Here, the designers decided on a grammar for a for-loop where parentheses are simply not allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), the syntax of a `for` loop is:

```
for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] suite ['else' ':' suite]
```

It's the `for` keyword, a list of expressions, the `in` keyword, and a list of tests. There's no provision for `exprlist 'in' testlist` to be surrounded by parentheses.

For parentheses to be allowed it would need to be something like this instead, where *expr* is a possibly-parenthesized expression:

```
for_stmt: 'for' expr ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] suite ['else' ':' suite]
```

That's not the grammar though.

> But shouldn't the brackets be ignored by the interpreter? Like `(a+b)/2` and `((a)+(b))/2` mean the same thing?

Parentheses are only allowed in predefined locations. They're not allowed just anywhere. You can't write `(a+)b/2` or `a+b(/2)`, right?

In the grammar, parentheses come from this production:

```
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [testlist_comp] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+ | '...' | 'None' | 'True' | 'False')
```

An *expr* can be many things. The most basic, indivisible type of *expr* is an *atom*: a name, a number, a string, and so on (the last line). Or another expression surrounded by parentheses (the first line).

Anywhere an expression is allowed, a parenthesized version of that expression is also allowed.

```
'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':'
```

The *exprlist* could be parenthesized. The *testlist* could be parenthesized. If you examine the grammar, both of those productions ultimately lead to the *atom* production. These parentheses are allowed:

```
for (i) in (a):
```

But you can't freely insert parentheses anywhere else. None of these are allowed:

```
for (i in a):
for i (in a):
(for) i in a:
(for i in) a:
```

Answer (score -2):

The expression `i in a` in isolation will evaluate to a boolean: is `i` in the sequence `a`?

When you put it in brackets, you tell the interpreter to work out its value before looking at the things around it, so it is like writing:

```py
for False:
```

except it's worse than that because `i` isn't defined.